VS Code does not offer autocompletions for magic methods
VS Code does not display hints for magic methods in Python. For example, I have no hints about comparison methods (__eq__, __cmp__, etc.). See the picture:

Is there a way to turn them on?
I have looked at all possible parameters of the IntelliSense platform and VS code editor, but I didn't find anything.

Just FYI, __cmp__ was a magic method back in Python 2, but not in Python 3.

Is this happening inside of a class definition?  If so, the screenshot does not show it.

__ge is not a valid prefix for __eq__, try def __eq

@rioV8, I specifically pointed out that this applies to all comparison methods. __ge__ is the greater or equal method, but it is also not highlighted

As said in Python's documentation, __cmp__ is not supported in Python 3.

The cmp() function should be treated as gone, and the __cmp__()
special method is no longer supported. Use __lt__() for sorting,
__eq__() with __hash__(), and other rich comparisons as needed. (If you really need the cmp() functionality, you could use the expression
(a > b) - (a < b) as the equivalent for cmp(a, b).)

When you want __eq__, the ge character you entered is not included in eq, so it cannot be retrieved. You can try typing def __eq or def __ and use the Ctrl Space shortcut to get all hints.

